# Parallelization of bin packing problem by OpenMp

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am learning open mp, and I want to parallelize well-known BinPacking problem. But the problem is what whatever I try, can't get correct solution ( the one I get with sequential verstion).

So far, I have tried multiple different versions (including reduction, tasks, schedule) but didn't get anything useful.

Below is my the most recent try.

```
int binPackingParallel(std::vector<int> weight, int n, int c)
{
    int resltut = 0;
    int bin_rem[n];
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:result)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bool done = false;
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < result && !done; j++) {
            int b ;
            #pragma omp atomic
            b = bin_rem[j] - weight[i];
            if ( b >= 0) {
                bin_rem[j] = bin_rem[j] - weight[i];
                done = true;
            }
        }
        if (!done) {
            #pragma omp critical
            bin_rem[result] = c - weight[i];
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

---

Edit: I made modification on starting problem, so now there is given number of bins N and we need to check if all elements can be put in N bins. I made this by using recursion, still my parallel version is slower.

```
bool can_fit_parallel(std::vector<int> arr, std::vector<int> bins, int n) {
// base case: if the array is empty, we can fit the elements
if (arr.empty()) {
    return true;
}

bool found = false;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule (dynamic,10)
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (bins[i] >= arr[0]) {
        bins[i] -= arr[0];
        if (can_fit_parallel(std::vector<int>(arr.begin() + 1, arr.end()), bins, n)) {
            found = true;
            #pragma omp cancel for

        }
        // if the element doesn't fit or if the recursion fails,
        // restore the bin's capacity and try the next bin
        bins[i] += arr[0];
    }
}

// if the element doesn't fit in any of the bins, return false
return found;
```

}

Any help would be great

Comment: This algorithm is difficult (maybe impossible) to parallelize efficiently. To learn OpenMP, I would use a simpler example.

Comment: I assume "reltsu" is a typo for "result"? A compilable example is helpful...

Comment: If you are not concerned about efficiency and are simply interested in learning OpenMP, you can correct the code by doing the following:
1) Remove `reduction` clause.
2) Use an atomic operation to increase `result++;`
3) Protect all reading and writing to the  `bin_rem` array by using atomic operations. 
4) Since `bin_rem[j]` is used 2 locations in your code, you must ensure that another thread has not changed its value between the accesses. 
5) Correct typos. Ps: You do not need variable `done`, simply use `break;`

Comment: Why is `bin_rem` of type `int` while `weight` is `unsigned long long`?

Comment: @JimCownie yes, it was a typo. I have make correction

Comment: @VictorEijkhout first I have tried on large sets, so I have used unsigned long long. After realizing that code have wrong output, I made change to int. I will edit example here, to make it just int

Comment: @Laci thanks, after some modifications this looks promising. Although I need as much acceleration as possible, I will probably reach twice the speed of sequential execution with these changes. Could you make this as an answer

Comment: @Din Due to false sharing this solution most probably will be slower that the serial code. if your goal is speed use a better search algorithm (e.g. use STL). How big is `n`? Note that your serial code has a bug `if (j == reltsu)` should be `if (!done)`.

Comment: @Laci I corrected the bug. n can be in the range 50 000 - 300 000, but also it can be fixed (adjusted by the algorithm for the best performance). Can you give me an example of some other algorithm that could work? Maybe some online algorithms like nextfit? I found out that this solution gives the most precise answer, since my goal is to achieve to get fastest parallel version that will give correct solution.

Comment: @Laci I made new version, and put it to edit of initial problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need parallelization to make your code significantly faster. You have implemented the [First Fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-fit_bin_packing) method (its complexity is O(n2)), but it can be significantly faster if you use binary search trees (O(n Log n)). To do so, you just have to use the standard library (`std::multiset`), in this example I have implemented the [BestFit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-fit_bin_packing) algorithm:

```
int binPackingSTL(const std::vector<int>& weight, const int n, const int c)
{
    std::multiset<int> bins;                        //multiset to store bins
    for (const auto x: weight) {
        const auto it=bins.lower_bound(x);        // find the best bin to accomodate x
        if(it==bins.end()){                         
          bins.insert(c - x);                       // if no suitale bin found insert a new one
        } else {
            //suitable bin found - replace it with a smaller value
            auto value=*it;         // store its value
            bins.erase(it);         // erase the old value
            bins.insert(value-x);   // insert the new value         
        }
    }
    return bins.size();             // number of bins 
}
```

In [my measurements](https://godbolt.org/z/be5P1vbMr), it is 100x times faster than your code in the case of `n=50000`

EDIT: Both algorithms mentioned above (First-Fit and Best-Fit) are approximations to the bin packing problem. To answer your revised question, you have to use an algorithm that finds the optimal solution. So, you need to find an algorithm for the exact solution, not an approximation. Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, you can consider using already available libraries such as [BPPLIB – A Bin Packing Problem Library](https://site.unibo.it/operations-research/en/research/bpplib-a-bin-packing-problem-library).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a reduction: that would cause each thread to have it own partial result, and you want `result` to be global. I think that putting a critical section around *two* statements might work.  The atomic statement is meaningless since it is not on a shared variable.

But there a deeper problem: each `i` iteration can write a result, which affects how far the search of the other iterations goes. That means that the outer iteration has to be sequential. (You really need to think hard about whether iterations are independent before you slap a parallel directive on them!) Maybe you can make the inner iteration parallel: it's a search, which would be a reduction on `j`. However that loop would have to be pretty dang long before you'd see a performance improvement.

This looks to me like the sort of algorithm that you'd have to reformulate before you can make it parallel.

Comment: I made a reformulation as suggested, and it is in edit of my post. Could you take a look